# Creating a distributable Java library that uses Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Looking for some advice before I start a minor project...

I have a Java EE project which uses Spring 3 and Hibernate 3.6 to access a database, in which I've created quite a few APIs to access the database.  There are several other applications that need to use these APIs (backed by the same database), so I'd like to break them out into distributable JARs.

Problem is - I can't figure out a good way to distribute a library that is backed by Hibernate.  I use annotations, not config files for Hibernate.  Each API has a singleton which, in my application, is setup as a Spring bean and consumes a SessionFactory.  The Spring bean (copied below) has a few configuration items.

So, my questions are:

1. I would like to decouple the library from Spring (so the other applications don't necessarily have to use Spring).  Is that realistic?
2. What is the best way to take a DataSource instance (the common
   denominator for each application), turn it into a SessionFactory and
   pass it to the singleton?
3. Is there a way to encapsulate the few hibernateProperties items from the bean below, so they're in the library rather than in a config file?
4. The singletons use the Spring transaction manager with the @Transactional annotation.  Obviously that's coupled with Spring, so I suppose I'd have to remove it if I want to make this Spring-agnostic?  Should I switch to programmatic transaction management?

So that's the story - does this sound doable?

Spring config:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="oracleDatabase" />
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.company.data.DataManagerSingleton</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">schema_name</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <value>com.company.data</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <qualifier value="ec" />
</bean>
```

Thanks.